# passing javascript variable value to swf in fdt

Tags: javascript, jquery, fdt

I am very new in FDT, I want to pass javascript variable value to FDT code.
I have no idea how to do it.

HTML Code:

```
<a id="player" href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="02">ABCD</a>
```

Javascript Code:

```
$('.list a').click(function(){ 
  var id = $(this).data("id");
}
```

In FDT, with id 02 there is SWF file link.

Or is there any another way to do it? Please help me.

Thanks in adcance.

Answer (score 2):

you need to use ExternalInterface in swf, to catch function calls from javascript

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

if (ExternalInterface.available){
    ExternalInterface.addCallback("changeText", changeTheText); 
}

function changeTheText(t:String):void {
    txtText.text = t;
}
```

JavaScript code

```
var flashObj = document.getElementById('flashObject');
<a href="#" onClick="flashObj.changeText('it works!');">Click me!</a>
```

Example here:
http://www.hardcode.nl/archives_155/article_334-call-javascript-function-from-as3-and-viceversa.htm

Search google for "javascript/as3 bridge"

Comment: Thanks a lot for commenting, but I am not getting it. Can you please elaborate this in words? please. I mentioned only one href link above but there are multiple links of href. Is this work for different links for different text?

as you said above `function changeTheText`, where it must be written? I have no idea how to do it. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @bFunc mentioned, I might advise doing your `onclick` event outside of the anchor tag, if possible. I find it best to target your elements that receive action via JS rather than embedded in the HTML code. This way, you can wrap the `flashObj.changeText` call in a `try/catch` to avoid JS errors (which may happen), and handle the error appropriately (i.e. if your SWF isn't available or loaded, like when a user doesn't have Flash Player installed).

For example:

HTML Code:

```
<a id="flash_bridge_link" href="#" onclick="javascript:void(0)">Click Me</a>
```

Javascript:

```
var flashLink = document.getElementById("flash_bridge_link");
var flashObj = document.getElementById("flashObject");
flashLink.onclick = function () {
    try {
        flashObj.changeText("it works!");
    } catch (error) {
        // Handle error as needed.
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hey thanks for answer. It works if I use as use it in .as file but its not properly working in .mxml file is there any another way to do it?

Comment: Hmm. I put together a little Hello World example using Flash Builder 4.6 to build my SWF, per your comment. Everything works for me. It uses SWFObject to embed the SWF to the page, and the JS logic from my answer above is included after `$(document).ready();` to ensure the SWF is written to the page. In the MXML code, the ExternalInterface stuff is set up after the `addedToStage` event to ensure the SWF is initialized and ready to go. In short, make sure the SWF is initialized and the JS doesn't call to it until the `$(document).ready()` is fired off.

Comment: Hey thanks I got where I was doing wrong. I am still stuck at one point. I have variable in javascript as `var moduleID = 10;` and want to access value 10 in mxml file. I am doing as `Alert.show("id is:" + moduleID);` but it alerts id is : 0. where I did wrong. 
Reply asap.

Comment: Could be a couple things. 
1. Make sure your var `moduleID` is accessible (i.e. a global var, not declared inside a function, etc). If you're not sure about this, do a Google search for "JavaScript variable scope" and ensure it's accessible at a global level.
2. Alternatively, make a JS function you can call from Flash, which will return the variable. For example, the JS function could be: `function getModuleID() { return moduleID; }`. Then, in your Flash, you'd reference it and set a Flash var to its value, like this: `var flashModuleID:Number = ExternalInterface.call('getModuleID');`

Comment: Also, I noticed your code from the previous comment was `Alert.show("id is:" + moduleID);`, which I'm assuming is ActionScript code in your MXML file. You can't directly reference JS variables (or any JS code) from AS code w/o the `ExternalInterface`. So try for the #2 option I outlined in my previous comment. Hopefully that will work.

Comment: Hey thanks for comment, I solved this problem by using FlashVars. Firstly I used ExternalInterface but there was an error to load SWF file so I switched to `FlashVars`. `FlashVar` is option to `ExternalInterface`.

Comment: Good to hear. Flashvars are a great way to pass in info to a SWF, so that's a good solution. If you need to grab values after the SWF loads (e.g. JS vars that may change as time goes on during a user's experience on a page), that's when ExternalInterface can be helpful, as well as JS calling Flash methods. Glad to hear everything is solved for you.